# How to show html containing mathjax without using webview

Tags: flutter, mathjax, flutter-html

`<p>যদি \(\mathrm{a+b=\sqrt{5}}\) এবং \(\mathrm{a-b=\sqrt{3}}\) হয়, তবে \(\mathrm{a^2+b^2=}\) কত?</p>`

I have about 100 strings like the above html string. I want to show this in flutter. I used `flutter_tex` package and it worked but since it uses webview it slow down the performance. `flutter_tex` takes so much time to render the string in webview. So for improving performance I want to avoid webview.

I read the flutter_html package documentation and guessed that it is possible using this but can't make the right code.

Here is a sample code taken from their documentation.

```
`Widget htmlWidget = Html(
data: r"""<tex>i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\vec x,t) = -\frac{\hbar}        {2m}\nabla^2\Psi(\vec x,t)+ V(\vec x)\Psi(\vec x,t)</tex>""",
customRender: {
"tex": (RenderContext context, _) => Math.tex(
context.tree.element!.text,
onErrorFallback: (FlutterMathException e) {
//return your error widget here e.g.
return Text(e.message);
},
),
},
tagsList: Html.tags..add('tex'),
);`
```

I am new in flutter. Can you help me to make the equivalent code for my provided above html string?

Thanks in advance.

I am trying with `flutter_tex` and it worked but very slow since it uses webview and I have many string so it make many webview at a time. I want a solution without webview.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#tex), the flutter_html package requires flutter_math plugin to render TeX. The flutter_math package is currently unmaintained, so you can use [flutter_math_fork](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_math_fork) instead.

1. Add [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) and [flutter_math_fork](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_math_fork) to your dependencies.
2. Replace every math equation start (`\(`) with `<tex>` and every equation end (`\)`) with `</tex>`. You can use the `replaceAll` method like this:

   ```
   data.replaceAll(r'\(', r'<tex>').replaceAll(r'\)', r'</tex>')
   ```

Use the widget like this:

```dart
Html(
  data:
      r'<p>যদি <tex>\mathrm{a+b=\sqrt{5}}</tex> এবং <tex>\mathrm{a-b=\sqrt{3}}</tex> হয়, তবে <tex>\mathrm{a^2+b^2=}</tex> কত?</p>',
  shrinkWrap: true,
  extensions: [
    TagExtension(
      tagsToExtend: {"tex"},
      builder: (extensionContext) {
        return Math.tex(
          extensionContext.innerHtml,
          textStyle: extensionContext.styledElement?.style
              .generateTextStyle(),
          onErrorFallback: (FlutterMathException e) {
            return Text(e.message);
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: is it possible without replacing every math equation start (`\()` with `<tex>` and every equation end (`\)`) with `</tex>` ? Because these come from database and all usage same syntax of mathjax.

Comment: No. flutter_html relies on the tags from the `tagsToExtend` property to know which part of the html data to render with extensions. You can automatically replace them like this: `data.replaceAll(r'\(', r'<tex>').replaceAll(r'\)', r'</tex>')` (I've edited my answer)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What should I do to work for chemistry formula also?

`<p>স্ফুটনাঙ্কের উচ্চক্রম অনুসারে \(\ce{HF, H2O, NH3}\) এবং \(\ce{CH4}\) যৌগসমূহকে তালিকাভূক্ত করলে নিচের কোনটি সঠিক হবে?</p>`

Comment: Perhaps worth a seperate question: How to render chemistry formula in TeX format without flutter_tex

Comment: Thanks. I posted another question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77838895/23261981